# How to change the text encoding for files in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, encoding, utf-8

I have the same problems as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705279/change-text-encoding-for-multiple-files-at-once-in-eclipse). However I will say that when I view the JSP page in the editor the accents are there (because the encoding is set to ISO-8859-1. Determined from content), changing this to UTF8 mangles the characters in the editor the same way as shown in the web browser. I really need to convert the whole project to UTF8 (I have set it to such in project preferences) but alas, I've wasted hours and gotten nowhere yet. Can anyone shed a light on this for me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before changing the content type

```
$ iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 < file.jsp > file-utf8.jsp
```

It worked for me - I'm on a mac.

if you google arroud you will find some shell scripts to do it recursively.

PS. I didn't find a easier way to do it. =/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However I somehow managed to change it on the windows dev way back then but can't remember how.